# Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when building for ios

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

i have been having this problem for the last 2 days and tried everything i found online to solve it and so far nothing worked for me, i'm really at a loss here and would appreciate help

error :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           12.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
   --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F9BC5C60-149E-456C-A45D-306B65B6064A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AB2DCA9D-6938-4DEE-8960-84C1DCBB3C0F, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:C147065E-2EB2-4572-B718-79C7B8DE9BCD, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:41C362BC-D235-40A3-8779-92646DE5A23E, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BDEEE9D0-B104-440F-A10B-B5CD9B70BAA8, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F5AFAF96-31F7-4BB3-B807-F2EAE7800890, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4C577B02-F793-40C8-BDD9-A17BFE12C296, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7D5D7CEB-674C-445C-9250-FFA1C2434794, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EC27FBBF-2C4A-4116-A985-2C66FBADB746, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4BE16D96-CA6C-444A-B645-F8F07A1D4A4A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:48FFF88B-9D55-4CE4-AE15-74AD11DEB824, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:13233AC1-5CF9-4081-924F-320DD8E04814, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:018E8A53-EDD5-4D8C-B998-91B0E07FA0A6, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A4D7ADE3-80D8-421E-8FAE-7F91715B06F1, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:70D65225-ED26-4CCB-B039-CD0A2DEE201F, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
   { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:866DF45E-A9E1-47D5-BC9F-F258E50BCB69, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:48DD8503-D214-4367-9187-4C26DD2EB9A9, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6A5EA463-9F84-4E20-AB88-3AB2500C5011, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:52C025F1-9B0D-40DB-97F6-B51978A105BD, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0F74B109-6E7F-498E-AA32-E5F9309AB909, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
   { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1D1F5B23-7AD5-45BC-907A-9D2C57A0337E, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
   ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode’s output:
↳
   /Users/ahmedaly/Developer/PushApp_Projects/fashion-hero-flutter/ios/Pods/Reachability/Reachability.m:465:63: warning: cast to smaller integer type ‘unsigned int’ from ‘Reachability *’ [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
                                NSStringFromClass([self class]), (unsigned int) self, [self currentReachabilityFlags]];
                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   1 warning generated.
In file included from /Users/ahmedaly/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.10/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:7:
/Users/ahmedaly/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.10/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: ‘Flutter/Flutter.h’ file not found
   #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   1 error generated.
   note: Using new build system
   note: Planning
   note: Build preparation complete
   note: Building targets in parallel
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited (sigterm)
```

flutter doctor:

```
 Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale
   en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.61.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

things i've tried:

- removing IOS folder inside my project then trying flutter create -flutter clean -pod install flutter run
- a lot of different ways people suggested that basically tried reseting and playing around pods

Comment: Have you tried to change the pod iOS version inside pod file?

platform :ios, '10.0'

Try changing it to 12.0

Comment: yeah i had tried that but it didn't work, just solved the problem right now though it was a dependency 'smartlook' causing the issue so i had to remove it

Comment: Check this link out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69978055/flutter-simulator-error-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit
This was my solution